# Unable to connect to php database with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error

I am writing a database class which is going to connect to my pdo database. This class is using this config file to get the information needed:

```
<?php
return [
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database_name' => 'books',
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'options' => []
];
```

And this is the database class:

```
<?php
class DB
{
    public static function connect($config)
    {
        try {
            return new PDO([
                $config['database_type'] . ':host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database_name'],
                $config['username'],
                $config['password'],
                $config['options']
            ]);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: PDO::__construct() expects parameter
>   1 to be string, array given in and etc...

I am wondering what I did wrong, sicne I don't see any syntax mistakes in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra set of brackets:

```
        return new PDO([
          ...
        ]);
```

... shouldn't have the [ and ] respectively; they're turning your four function parameters into a single array parameter.  You want simply

```
        return new PDO(
          ...
        );
```

HTH!

Comment: You were correct. Completely my bad. Didn't even notice it. Thank you!